# Is it possible to copy couchdb directly to sdcard on android devices?

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase

I see that the couchdbs are stored in the `/sdcard/Android/data/my.app.package/db/` as `.couch` files. I was trying to copy the `couchdb` directly to `sdcard` and make the couchdb service recognize it.  We have a large amount of data in the cloud stored in couchdb and replicating it everytime during testing takes a lot of time and being able to copy it directly will hasten the development process. Is it possible to do this? if yes, how and is there any special care needed to make the android couchbase service recognize the couchdbs copied?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to copy .couch files between instances of CouchDB that share a common database format. If you've got two 1.1.0 CouchDB's, then you can `cp` (or similar) the .couch file into a running instance of another 1.1.0 CouchDB and it should "just work." *Sometimes*, you can successfully copy a .couch file "up" a version (ex: 1.1.0 to 1.2.0), but your mileage may vary.

I'm not sure what version of CouchDB the last active CouchDB for Android uses, but theoretically it would work the same--once you know what version it's based on.

TouchDB, the new CouchDB replication compatible database from Couchbase does **not** use the same .couch format, nor does Couchbase Server 2.0. Copying a .couch file from any version of CouchDB into one of those will **not** work as the database formats are significantly different (especially for TouchDB which uses SQLite underneath).

CouchDB-to-CouchDB, though, is typically fine as long as you keep an eye on the version numbers.