# Is SD Card definitely required when using CouchDB on Android

Tags: android, couchdb, couchbase

I am trying to save some json data on Android phone version >=2.2 for later querying and offline use. I found out that CouchDB can be used on Android. But some threads said it is a requirement to have a SD card installed in order to use CouchDB, such as:

[What are requirements to use CouchDB on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8399070/what-are-requirements-to-use-couchdb-on-android)
and [Is it possible to copy couchdb directly to sdcard on android devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9214545/is-it-possible-to-copy-couchdb-directly-to-sdcard-on-android-devices?rq=1)

Not all our customers have SD card installed on their Android phones, so I wonder if it is still a requirement to use CouchDB on Android and is it possible to use just local storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Not all our customers have SD card installed on their Android phones,
>   so I wonder if it is still a requirement to use CouchDB on Android and
>   is it possible to use just local storage?

So it depends on more factors, first and most important one is size of database. If your database will have bigger size for example 10-100+ MB it's not very good and effective to copy db into internal storage or for example into assets folder and read from there.

I think nobody can't give you right answer but it's up to you whose approach you will choose.

There are also another ways for example you can parse `JSON` and then serialize it into binary file that will have smaller size, save it into internal storage / sd card and if you want to read just deserialize it and get data.

Comment: Thanks. Actually, I can expect the size of the database is very small, less than 1MB. So I think there won’t be any serious problem to save it locally. One important reason I want to use CouchDB instead of local JSON files is that the app need to query (like querying a database) and update the JSON data frequently offline, and then synchronise it with remote database later. Is it easy to do so in using local JSON files? Many thanks.

Comment: @afterglowlee so you can use database for sure, if size will be only 1 mb and not much more so there is not problem save db on local storage.